# Magento 2 - URLs trailing slash redirection

Tags: magento-2.1, url, url-rewrite

I configured my Magento 2 store to ends with trailing slash. This work great.

But when I browse the same page without trailing slash, it redirects to a 404 error page, and not to the trailing slash versión.

Why does it not redirect automatically? Do I need to configure something?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I resolve the problem tunning my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^robots.txt - [L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml - [L]
RewriteRule ^BingSiteAuth.xml - [L]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/rest/*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/customer/*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/labotiga_admin/*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/redsys/*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/category/*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/recaptcha/*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

The first part like robots.txt is to not add trailing slash on these files.

The second part of /customer/* is to not add trailing slash also on some important directories

Finally we add trailing slash with last rule.

Hope you use it or help to solve these problems.