# Put a trailing slash at the end of CMS URL without redirection

Tags: magento-1.9, url, cms

I would to put a trailing slash at the end of my CMS URL, but without make redirection when it's possible : I want to put this slash when the URL is build.

In the BO, in CMS page, we can define url key, for instance "my-url". In the website, we can access to this url by :
`example.com/my-url` or `example.com/my-url/` (both work).

In CMS bloc, we can call this url with the following code :
`{{store url="my-url"}}` or `{{store url="my-url/"}}`.

So, what is the most recommended ?

1 - Update all content CMS bloc and change `{{store url="my-url"}}` by `{{store url="my-url/"}}`.
=> but how change that in mass ?

2 - Override the url build and have this url `example.com/my-url/` even if it's `{{store url="my-url"}}` in the bloc.
=> but how make this override ?

3 - Another idea ?

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use only .htaccess for this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.)
 RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

And here is htaccess solution for Magento

[Magento 2 - URLs trailing slash redirection](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/176412/magento-2-urls-trailing-slash-redirection)

And for Magento 1 for programatic change of URL
[Internal links to end with a trailing slash](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6314/internal-links-to-end-with-a-trailing-slash)

I didn't check this:

```
    public function getUrl($routePath = null,
 $routeParams = null){ 
$url = parent::getUrl($routePath, $routeParams);
 if (substr($_GET['page'], -1) !== '/') { 
$parts = explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 2); 
    $uri = 'http://example.com'.$parts[0].'/'.(isset($parts[1]) ? '?'.$parts[1] : ''); 
    header('Location: '.$uri, true, 301); exit; }
         return $url; }
```

Comment: I said I don't want to make redirection ;) And I'm on Magento 1 not 2

Comment: Sorry I update my answer , please read topic from link, there is also discussion about "What is the point?"

Comment: Err.. Here to, you make a redirection : header('Location: '.$uri, true, 301);. I really want to do that without redirection. I will try to override getUrl and see if it's possible

Comment: Maybe export all products to csv and add slash in editor on "url_key" and import.

Comment: It's not products, it's CMS page, and we can't add slash in the url-key (not work for me)